# Gsap responsive menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I'M new in gsap which is JavaScript animation library. I found this cool navigation code on YouTube. So I tried to convert it into responsive, so there will no need of menu button for the screen sizes bigger than 1000px and for screen size smaller than 1000px it will work default. I've made some changes, but they didn't go as I expect. So, can anyone help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$('ul.main-menu li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).siblings('li').find('ul.submenu:visible').length) {
    $('ul.submenu').slideUp('normal');
  }
  $(this).find('ul.submenu').slideToggle('normal');
});

var t1 = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});

t1.to(".menu", 0.8, {
  autoAlpha: 1
});

t1.staggerFrom(".main-menu li a:not(.submenu li a)", 1, {
  opacity: 1,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
}, 0.1);

t1.from(".submenu", 0.8, {
  autoAlpha: 0
});

t1.staggerFrom(".media ul li", 1, {
  opacity: 0,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
}, 0.1, "-=2");

t1.from(".call", 1, {
  delay: -2,
  opacity: 0,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
});

t1.from(".mail", 1, {
  delay: -1.6,
  opacity: 0,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
});

t1.reverse();

$(document).on("click", ".menu-btn", function() {
  t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
});

$(document).on("click", ".close-menu", function() {
  t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

.hero-section {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: end;
}

.close-menu {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #121212;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .close-menu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 21%;
    margin-top: 8%;
  }
  .nav ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .main-menu-item {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  .main-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  .submenu-item a {
    color: grey;
  }
  .submenu li {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  a ion-icon {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  .contact {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 24%;
  }
  .contact p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: grey;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
  }
  .media {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 22%;
  }
  .media ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .media ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .contact {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hero-section">
    <h1>Responsive Drop-down Menu Concept</h1>

    <div class="menu-btn">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="close-menu">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Our Products &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Fonts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Mockups</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Presets</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Portfolio &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Timeless flow</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Foretime</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Never again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Departure</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Our Story</a>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Contact &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Call now</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Mail us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <p class="call">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+91 29000 23000</p>
      <p class="mail">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;codegridweb@gmail.com</p>
    </div>

    <div class="media">
      <ul>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you expect ??

Comment: @KunalTanwar I'M expecting that the menu should be horizontally aligned at top-right corner, like standard menu's of website for the screen size bigger than 1000px without any toggle button.

Comment: _for the screen size bigger than 1000px_? You want hamburger icon to be visible for the screens bigger than 1000px, right?? Then what about the small screen or screen < 1000px, the hamburger icon should be hidden for that? And also what do you mean by _without any toggle button_ ??

Comment: @KunalTanwar For the screens bigger than 1000px , hamburger menu should be hidden. And visible for devices screen size less than 1000px .

Comment: Still not getting! without toggle button automatically opens the menu while screen reaches less than 1000px ?

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran In simple language, I want "Responsive Menu". For example 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QdfhAeMB0k'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all your `.menu-btn` content up to `.media ul li` inside a media query

Something like that:

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #121212;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .close-menu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 21%;
    margin-top: 8%;
  }
  .nav ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .main-menu-item {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  .main-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  .submenu-item a {
    color: grey;
  }
  .submenu li {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  a ion-icon {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  .contact {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 24%;
  }
  .contact p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: grey;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
  }
  .media {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 22%;
  }
  .media ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .media ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain 2 menus. One for desktop and other for mobile. Hide the desktop one for `max-width:1000px`. Have provided the code. Let me know if it works for you.

```js
$('ul.main-menu li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).siblings('li').find('ul.submenu:visible').length) {
    $('ul.submenu').slideUp('normal');
  }
  $(this).find('ul.submenu').slideToggle('normal');
});

var t1 = new TimelineMax({
  paused: true
});

t1.to(".menu", 0.8, {
  autoAlpha: 1
});

t1.staggerFrom(".main-menu li a:not(.submenu li a)", 1, {
  opacity: 1,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
}, 0.1);

t1.from(".submenu", 0.8, {
  autoAlpha: 0
});

t1.staggerFrom(".media ul li", 1, {
  opacity: 0,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
}, 0.1, "-=2");

t1.from(".call", 1, {
  delay: -2,
  opacity: 0,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
});

t1.from(".mail", 1, {
  delay: -1.6,
  opacity: 0,
  y: 10,
  ease: Power3.easeInOut
});

t1.reverse();

$(document).on("click", ".menu-btn", function() {
  t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
});

$(document).on("click", ".close-menu", function() {
  t1.reversed(!t1.reversed());
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
}

.hero-section {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;

 }

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: end;
}

.close-menu {
  display: none;
}
.menu.desktop{
visibility:visible !important;
opacity:1 !important;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
 }

@media(max-width: 1000px) {
  .menu.desktop{
    display:none;
  }
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #121212;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .close-menu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 21%;
    margin-top: 8%;
  }
  .nav ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .main-menu-item {
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  .main-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  .submenu-item a {
    color: grey;
  }
  .submenu li {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }
  a ion-icon {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  .contact {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 24%;
  }
  .contact p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: grey;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
  }
  .media {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 22%;
  }
  .media ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .media ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: grey;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding-right: 16px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }
  .contact {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hero-section">
    <h1>Responsive Drop-down Menu Concept</h1>

    <div class="menu-btn">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="close-menu">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Our Products &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Fonts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Mockups</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Presets</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Portfolio &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Timeless flow</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Foretime</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Never again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Departure</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Our Story</a>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Contact &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Call now</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Mail us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <p class="call">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+91 29000 23000</p>
      <p class="mail">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;codegridweb@gmail.com</p>
    </div>

    <div class="media">
      <ul>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu desktop">
    <div class="close-menu">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Our Products &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Fonts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Mockups</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Presets</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Portfolio &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Timeless flow</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Foretime</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Never again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Departure</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Our Story</a>
        </li>

        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Contact &nbsp; <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></a>

          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Call now</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-item">
              <a href="#">Mail us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <p class="call">
        <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+91 29000 23000</p>
      <p class="mail">
        <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;codegridweb@gmail.com</p>
    </div>

    <div class="media">
      <ul>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```